# A good Java library for network math

Tags: java, math, networking

I'm looking for a Java library that is geared towards network math and already tested.  Nothing particularly fancy, just something to hold ips and subnets, and do things like print a subnet mask or calculate whether an IP is within a given subnet.

Should I roll my own, or is there already a robust library for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We developed a Java IPv4 arithmetic library ourselves. 
See it here: http://tufar.com/ipcalculator/
It is under BSD license.

Answer (score 5):

[org.apache.lenya.ac.IPRange](http://lenya.apache.org/apidocs/2.0/org/apache/lenya/ac/IPRange.html) appears to have these features.

The Apache Lenya project is an open-source content management system.  It uses the Apache License, so you may be able to reuse just the code you need. (But as always, read the [license](http://lenya.apache.org/index/license.html) yourself; don't trust legal advice from some guy on the internet! :-)

Comment: org.apache.lenya.ac.IPRange can certainly be modified to meet my needs, thanks for the response. That said, I was hoping to find something more general, like a Java equivalent to Perl's IP::NetAddr.

Answer (score 2):

The [open-source IPAddress Java library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/) can do ip address manipulation such as conversion to/from ipv4/ipv6 and subnet checking.  Disclaimer: I am the project manager.

It handles various network math operations, such as masking, bitwise or, setting prefix lengths, switch address to prefix block, iterating through a subnet, checking containment, replacing address segments, reversing addresses, calculating subnet intersection, subtracting one subnet from another, and others.

Here is some example code for testing if an ipv6 address is in a given subnet:

```
    String ipv6 = "2001:db8:57AB:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001";
    String ipv6subnet = "2001:db8::/32";
    String ipv4 = "1.2.3.4";
    try {
        IPAddressString ipv6addrstr = new IPAddressString(ipv6);
        IPAddressString ipv6addrsubnetstr = new IPAddressString(ipv6subnet);
        IPAddressString ipv4addrstr = new IPAddressString(ipv4);

        IPAddress ipv6addr = ipv6addrstr.toAddress();
        IPAddress ipv6addrsubnet = ipv6addrsubnetstr.toAddress();
        IPAddress ipv4mappedaddr = ipv4addrstr.toAddress().toIPv6();

        System.out.println(ipv6addrsubnet + " contains " + ipv6addr + ": " + ipv6addrsubnet.contains(ipv6addr)); //
        System.out.println(ipv6addrsubnet + " contains " + ipv4mappedaddr + ": " + ipv6addrsubnet.contains(ipv4mappedaddr)); //

    } catch(AddressStringException e) {
        //e.getMessage has validation error
    }
```

output:

```
2001:db8::/32 contains 2001:db8:57ab::1 is true
2001:db8::/32 contains ::ffff:102:304 is false
```